# VBA Copy row based on last unique value in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a summary of data in an excel spreadsheet. I want to copy the last unique row based off the first column Here is an example of the data:

```
DocOrd#   text    Value

1         text    .1
1         text    .2
1         text    .3
1         text    .4
2         text     2
2         text     4
2         text     6
2         text     8
3         text     1
3         text     2
3         text     3
3         text     4
```

What I want:

```
DocOrd#   text    Value

1         text    .4
2         text     8 
3         text     4
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: When you say **unique** row what do you mean? The last entry in a given `DocOrd#`?

Answer (score 0):

This might help - it loops through your data (assume in `Sheet1` starting in cell `A1`) and gets last entry for each `DocOrd#` and places it on `Sheet2`

```
Sub CopyLastEntry()
    Dim entries As Range, entry As Range, cnt As Long

    Set entries = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) //Change as per your s/sheet
    cnt = 1

    For Each entry In entries
        If entry <> entry.Offset(1, 0) Then
            Range(entry, entry.Offset(0, 3)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("A" & cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next entry
End Sub
```